# New module from sibling directory can't be imported

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a problem with importing a new module from a sibling folder, while importing old one from the same location works well.

The folder tree looks like this:

```
root :
 |
 |__SiblingA:
 |    \A.py
 |     
 |__SiblingB:
 |    \ __init__.py
 |    \B.py
 |    \C.py
```

in A.py I have two imports:

```
    from SiblingB.B import ClassB
    from SiblingB.C import ClassC
```

Where first one works and the second doesn't. I get an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named SiblingB.C`

The same imports placed in root directory works well, so it shouldn't be problem with some error in C.py
B.py is an old file and has been imported in that way previously, while C.py is a new one.
**init**.py in SiblingB is empty

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem? In the first place, it looks strange that the first import works in that way, so maybe that's the direction to look for?

Comment: You have a typo, in the error you mention a SiblingC.C but you are importing SiblingB.C

Comment: Sorry about that, edited now. That was only a typo in my post, not present in my code.